# How to extract orientation information from videos?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ruby, iphone-sdk-3.0, ffmpeg

After surfing through tons of documentation on the web it seems that the iPhone always shoots the video at a 480x360 aspect ratio and applies a transformation matrix on the video track. (480x360 may change but its always the same for a given device)

Here is a way of modifying the ffmpeg source within a iOS project and accessing the matrix http://www.seqoy.com/correct-orientation-for-iphone-recorded-movies-with-ffmpeg/

Here is a cleaner way of finding the transformation matrix in iOS-4
[How to detect (iPhone SDK) if a video file was recorded in portrait orientation, or landscape.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627940/how-to-detect-iphone-sdk-if-a-video-file-was-recorded-in-portrait-orientation)

How can the orientation of the video be extracted in either of the options below - 
- iOS 3.2 
- ffmpeg (through the command line server side) 
- ruby

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since I can't comment on enobrev's answer. FFMPEG can now return orientation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8994482/949714

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since most Cameras store their rotation/orientation within the exif-metadata, i would suggest using [`exifttool`](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and the a ruby wrapper gem called [`mini_exiftool`](https://github.com/janfri/mini_exiftool) which is actively maintained.

Install exiftool:

`apt-get exiftool || brew install exiftool || port install exiftool`

or use what ever package manager is available

Install mini_exiftool:

`gem install mini_exiftool`

Try it:

```
irb>
require 'mini_exiftool'
movie = MiniExiftool.new('test_movie.mov')
movie.orientation #=> 90
```

cheers

Comment: Marked correct for suggesting a gem version and the adding references. Thanks!

Comment: exiftool version 10.05 is giving me movie.rotation now

Answer (score 11):

You can use `ffprobe`. No need for any `grep`, or any other additional processes, or any regex operations to parse the output as shown in other answers.

## If you want the rotate metadata:

Command:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream_tags=rotate -of default=nw=1:nk=1 input.mp4
```

Example output:

```
90
```

## If you want the display matrix rotation side data:

Command:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries side_data=rotation -of default=nw=1:nk=1 input.mp4
```

Example output:

```
-90
```

## If you want the display matrix:

Command:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries side_data=displaymatrix -of default=nw=1:nk=1 input.mp4
```

Example output:

```
00000000:            0       65536           0
00000001:       -65536           0           0
00000002:     15728640           0  1073741824
```

---

### What the options mean

- `-loglevel error` Omit the header and other info from output.
- `-select_streams v:0` Only process the first video stream and ignore everything else. Useful if your input contains multiple video streams and you only want info from one.
- `-show_entries stream_tags=rotate` Chooses to output the `rotate` tag from the video stream.
- `-of default=nw=1:nk=1` Use [*default* output format](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#default), but omit including the section header/footer wrappers and each field key.

### Output format

The output from `ffprobe` can be [formatted in several ways](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Writers). For example, JSON:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries stream_tags=rotate -of json input.mp4
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "tags": {
                "rotate": "90"
            },
            "side_data_list": [
                {

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Hi @llgoan, I tried to follow your answer to extract motion vectors using ffprobe. Could you help me with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67541099/ffmpeg-get-motion-vectors-without-decoding-the-video ?

Answer (score 10):

From what I've found thus far, ffmpeg doesn't have the ability to detect iPhone's orientation.  But, the open source library, [mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en/Download) can.  A command line example:

```
$ mediainfo test.mp4 | grep Rotation
Rotation                         : 90°
```

More example output from the same iphone video:

```
Video
ID                               : 1
Format                           : AVC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                   : Baseline@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC           : No
Format settings, ReFrames        : 1 frame
Codec ID                         : avc1
Codec ID/Info                    : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                         : 7s 941ms
Bit rate mode                    : Variable
Bit rate                         : 724 Kbps
Width                            : 480 pixels
Height                           : 360 pixels
Display aspect ratio             : 4:3
Rotation                         : 90°
Frame rate mode                  : Variable
Frame rate                       : 29.970 fps
Minimum frame rate               : 28.571 fps
Maximum frame rate               : 31.579 fps
Color space                      : YUV
Chroma subsampling               : 4:2:0
Bit depth                        : 8 bits
Scan type                        : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.140
Stream size                      : 702 KiB (91%)
Title                            : Core Media Video
Encoded date                     : UTC 2011-06-22 15:58:25
Tagged date                      : UTC 2011-06-22 15:58:34
Color primaries                  : BT.601-6 525, BT.1358 525, BT.1700 NTSC, SMPTE 170M
Transfer characteristics         : BT.709-5, BT.1361
Matrix coefficients              : BT.601-6 525, BT.1358 525, BT.1700 NTSC, SMPTE 170M
```

Comment: I've also recently found a link explaining how to modify ffmpeg to extract this info http://www.seqoy.com/correct-orientation-for-iphone-recorded-movies-with-ffmpeg/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I marked the mini_exiftool answer as correct because its integrated via a gem. mediainfo seems legit too.

Comment: Hah just bumped into this while looking up iOS video metadata. @enobrev

Comment: To write to a variable: ROTATION="$(mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Rotation%" video.mp4)"
echo $ROTATION

Answer (score 4):

ffmpeg reports the metadata with the rotation value for .mov files:

```
ffmpeg -i myrotatedMOV.mov
```

....

```
Duration: 00:00:14.31, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 778 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360, 702 kb/s, 29.98 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 180
      creation_time   : 2013-01-09 12:47:36
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 62 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-01-09 12:47:36
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
```

In my application I pull it out with regex, ie in python:

```
import subprocess, re    
cmd = 'ffmpeg -i %s' % pathtofile

p = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd.split(" "),
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
    close_fds=True
)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

reo_rotation = re.compile('rotate\s+:\s(?P<rotation>.*)')
match_rotation = reo_rotation.search(stderr)
rotation = match_rotation.groups()[0]
```

I havent tried this with a wide range of videos, only a couple .movs recorded from an iphone5, using ffmpeg version 1.0.  But so far so good.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @HdN8's answer, but without the python regex:

```
$ ffprobe   -show_streams any.MOV  2>/dev/null  | grep rotate
TAG:rotate=180
```

Or JSON:

```
$ ffprobe -of json  -show_streams IMG_8738.MOV  2>/dev/null  | grep rotate
"rotate": "180",
```

Or you could parse the JSON (or other output format).

Comment: You can [avoid `grep` and use `ffprobe` alone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41306388/1109017).

Answer (score 1):

I have extracted on iOS using an AVAssetExportSession, AVMutableComposition and the input AVAssetTrack's preferredTransform.  I concatenate the preferred transform with a transformation to fill the target size.

After exporting to a file, I upload using ASIHTTPRequest to my rails server and send the data to Amazon S3 using paperclip.