# Get Time Stamp/Location of iOS Video

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I can get the .MOV file with the Image Picker, but how can I find the location it was taken at and the time it was taken?

My image picker:
    - (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

```
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

// Handle a movie capture
if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef)mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
    == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

    NSString *movieFile = [[info objectForKey:
                            UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:movieFile];

    NSLog(@"Movie File %@",movieURL);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the location it was taken but you can use [`File Attribute Keys`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW2) to get the `NSFileCreationDate` using [`attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath:error:). There is a convenience method on `NSDictionary` [`fileCreationDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/fileCreationDate)

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:movieFile error:&error];
if (!attributes) {
    // Use the error
}
NSDate *createdDate = [attributes fileCreationDate];
```

If you want to access the meta-data on the MOV file you can have a look at the [EXIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287603/how-to-extract-orientation-information-from-mov-videos-created-on-the-iphone-usi) data, I don't know if there is a iOS library for this though.

Comment: Thank you very much. You should edit the last line to be `NSDate *createdDate = [attributes objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];` instead. It returned the whole date instead of just part.

Comment: As per the docs [`fileCreationDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/fileCreationDate) is the same as `[attributes objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate]`, are you saying this is not the case?!

Comment: Nope I miss read my console. You are completely right. My apologies.

Comment: Ah no problem! Just wanted to check. Hope this is what you're looking for too :)