# The entire frame is rotated after video capture

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, opencv3.0

frame variables pixel is entire frame

environment

- python version

```
3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
```

- opencv version

```
opencv-contrib-python==4.1.2.30
opencv-python==4.1.2.30
```

moviefile
30seconds

frame
height = 1920, width = 1080

```py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file_path)
frames = []
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        frames.append(frame)
    else:
        break
plt.imshow(frames[0])
```

When executed
height = 1080, width = 1920

How do I ?
Thanks

Comment: So only your width and height got flipped? Or the entire frame is rotated?

Comment: the entire frame is rotated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your video is rotated by **metadata** settings, and not encoded as 1080x1920.

The most probable explanation is that the video resolution is 1920x1080 (width=1920, and height=1080) [this is the standard resolution of FullHD video].
It is also probable that the video is captured with the camera rotated by 90 degrees.

Instead of decoding the video, rotating each frame, and encoding the frame, it's possible to add metadata to the video file, that marks the player to rotate the video when playing.
Adding metadata is more efficient (takes minimal time) and may have better quality (because it saves decoding and encoding stages).

Here is an example of rotating mp4 by setting metadata using [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/): [Rotate mp4 videos without re-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031557/rotate-mp4-videos-without-re-encoding).

When OpenCV reads the video frame, it reads it in the original orientation (1920x1080 and not 1080x1920).

This is a common convention regarding most of the video metadata - OpenCV assumes that you know that the metadata flag is set to "rotated", and assumes you are in charge of rotating the frame before displaying it (your Python program suppose to do the Players job).

Here is an example of creating sample mp4 video file using FFmpeg (in command line):

```
ffmpeg -y -r 10 -f lavfi -i testsrc=rate=10:size=198x108 -t 5 -c:v libx264 vid0.mp4
```

Here is an example of rotating the video by setting the metadata:

```
ffmpeg -i vid0.mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 vid90.mp4
```

In the following Python code, the frame shape of both videos is the same: `(108, 198, 3)`  (width=198, height=108):

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# video_file_path = 'vid0.mp4'

video_file_path = 'vid90.mp4'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file_path)
frames = []
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        frames.append(frame)
    else:
        break

plt.imshow(frames[0])
```

You can check the video metadata using [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) tool:

[image]

Reading the metadata in Python is more difficult than I thought (I never tried it).
You may find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44380432/opencv-video-looks-good-but-frames-are-rotated-90-degrees).
*[Now I realized your question is probably duplicated].*

First video frame of `vid90` in MPC-HC Player:
[image]

First video frame of `vid90` in Python (matplotlib):
[image]