# Unable to find a suitable output format for 'protocols'

Tags: shell, ffmpeg

I was trying to analyse a video with ffmpeg and it gives this error. I have referred to other sources but those solutions do not seem to work.

```
[NULL @ 0x24eb600] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'protocols'
protocols: Invalid argument
```

I have a video currently hosting on Google Cloud Storage and I want to use `ffprobe` to study its orientation. This is the command I use.

```
ffprobe -v error -show_streams -show_format https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/filename.mp4 | grep rotation
```

I am currently running on Debian Jessie and I installed `ffmpeg` from source.

Here's my installation script

```
cd ffmpeg-3.4.1
./configure --enable-shared
make
make install
ldconfig
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: No need for `grep`. See `ffprobe` examples in [How to extract orientation information from videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41306388/1109017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some protocols are missing when you build your `ffmpeg`. I am suspecting `https` is not enabled in your protocol list. Please check the list of supported protocols with `ffmpeg -protocols` and see whether `https` is on the list.

You will need to recompile `ffmpeg` with `openssl` to enable streaming video over `https`

**Install OpenSSL**

```
apt-get install openssl
```

**Configure FFMPEG with OpenSSL**

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-openssl
```

Comment: Thank you! I rebuilt ffmpeg with ssl and its working now!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable an additional external library for HTTPS support. FFmpeg supports several libraries:

## openssl

- package: **libssl-dev** (Debian/Ubuntu), **openssl-devel** (RHEL/CentOS)
- ffmpeg configure option: `--enable-openssl`

## gnutls

- package: **libgnutls28-dev** (Debian/Ubuntu), **gnutls-devel** (RHEL/CentOS)
- ffmpeg configure option: `--enable-gnutls`

## LibreSSL (via libtls)

- package: none available
- ffmpeg configure option: `--enable-libtls`