# opencv: video height and width are reported same for vertical and horizontal

Tags: opencv, video, dimensions

I have a bunch of videos from an iPhone and am trying to get their width and height programmatically using opencv. Here is my code:

```
import os, glob
import cv2
ff = glob.glob("*.m??") + glob.glob("*.M??")
for f in ff:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(f)
    w, h = (int(cap.get(i)) for i in (3, 4))
    cap.release()
    print("%s: %dx%d" % (f, w, h))
```

The problem is, the result is always the same: 1920x1080, -- regardless of whether the movies is horizontal (1920*1080) or vertical (I would expect 1080*1920).

Any ideas how to fix this? Maybe there is a flag somewhere that tells if it's Horiz or Vert? I didn't find anything here 
[at opencv docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html)...
Thank you!

Comment: the camera always records in horizontal mode, you'll have to read the "rotation information" of the device/video and rotate the video manually. Maybe OpenCV does not have options to read rotation information.

Comment: Thank you Micka, but as I wrote I am looking for exactly that – some sort of a flag... There is nothing that seems relevant to me here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention I am working with *.MOV videos.

Comment: BTW: after I convert the video from MOV to mp4, the library reports correctly the dimensions of *mp4 (i.e. w > h for horizontal and w < h for vertical).

Comment: how did you convert? Probably the converter alpplication did rotate the images.

Comment: I used ffmpeg (stand–alone binary cmd line), I didn't give it any dimensions as parameters, it "figured it out" somehow. 
Note: this does not solve my problem, I need to know the dimensions before conversion.

Comment: I think it is not possible to get orientation with opencv - you can use ffmpeg to get orientation data (see [how-to-extract-orientation-information-from-videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287603/how-to-extract-orientation-information-from-videos/14237677#14237677))

Comment: Dmitrii Z: Hah! :)  It's called a KLUDGE but definitely works for me, thank you!!!

Comment: Off-topic: 
I accidentally clicked twice on Dmitrii Z's comment's up–arrow, and now I cannot fix it, receiving:   
"You've already undone your vote on this comment, you cannot upvote it again".
Any suggestions?

Comment: @VladK. Yeah, don't worry about it, just keep it in mind for the future ;) | BTW, if you have a working solution, then by all means post it as a self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently all I needed to do is install the latest ffmpeg (which took some effort:).

```
ffmpeg -i <flnm>
```

outputs, among other things, a line with "rotate" in it, like this:

> ```
> Metadata:
>   rotate          : 90
>   creation_time   : 2015-12-09T00:28:42.000000Z
>   handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
>   encoder         : H.264
> ```

I found four cases: values 90, 180, 270 for rotate, or a line with 'rotate' is absent (== no rotation). To my needs, 90 and 270 correspond to "vertical" (.a.k.a. "portrait"), so my problem is solved.

Parsing is trivial, I don't think anybody wants my code here. Just a small note: you need to catch stderr rather than stdout from ffmeg.

Thanks all!