# FFmpeg get motion vectors without decoding the video

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, h.264

I would like to access the motion vectors of an h264 video stream without decoding the video. I know that this show the video and the motion vectors:

`ffplay -i myvideo.avi -flags2 +export_mvs -vf codecview=mv=pf+bf+bb`

How can I avoid decoding the entire video to save CPU? The reason I want to do that is that I’ll then need to parse this data in Python.

EDIT
I tried using `ffprobe` with

```
ffprobe -i my_video.mp4 -flags2 +export_mvs -print_format json -show_frames
```

It prints many information:

```
  {
            "media_type": "video",
            "stream_index": 0,
            "key_frame": 0,
            "pkt_pts": 2513990,
            "pkt_pts_time": "27.933222",
            "pkt_dts": 2510990,
            "pkt_dts_time": "27.899889",
            "best_effort_timestamp": 2513990,
            "best_effort_timestamp_time": "27.933222",
            "pkt_duration": 3000,
            "pkt_duration_time": "0.033333",
            "pkt_pos": "1157994",
            "pkt_size": "262",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720,
            "pix_fmt": "yuvj420p",
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "pict_type": "P",
            "coded_picture_number": 559,
            "display_picture_number": 0,
            "interlaced_frame": 0,
            "top_field_first": 0,
            "repeat_pict": 0,
            "color_range": "pc",
            "color_space": "bt709",
            "color_primaries": "bt709",
            "color_transfer": "bt709",
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "side_data_list": [
                {
                    "side_data_type": "Motion vectors"
                }
            ]
        },
```

As you can side, `Motion vectors` are mentioned in the `side_data_type`. How can I print them?
I tried with

```
ffprobe -i my_video.mp4 -flags2 +export_mvs -print_format json -show_frames -show_entries side_data="Motion vectors"
```

but it does not seem to add any information. I could change `"Motion vectors"`  to any other value without errors so I guess that's not point to the correct data.

Comment: I respectfully disagree that this question lacks focus. This questioner asked a single, focused, question. Just because the results they want are buried in the Golomb-coded opacity of the H.264 bitstream, and just because they're hard to interpret even when extracted doesn't make the question unfocused.

Comment: Check this out.  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24814/extracting-motion-vectors-from-h-264-bitstream

Comment: I looked at that discussion but I can't find a running code. I am currently trying with ffprobe because I feel I am close to a solution. Could you see if you know how to fix the error above? I have just edited the post. Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you manage to solve this? @user1315621

Comment: Hi @XinyaoWang , I didn't find a solution. If I remember correctly, the C API provides the data, but not the Python API.

Comment: Similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/1736825/how-to-extrack-motion-vector-data-without-decoding-the-whole-video