# Rotate Video after picked from UIImagePickerController to upload to server

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

So I've seen these answers and many others:

[How to detect (iPhone SDK) if a video file was recorded in portrait orientation, or landscape.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627940/how-to-detect-iphone-sdk-if-a-video-file-was-recorded-in-portrait-orientation)

[How do I rotate a video from UIImagePickerController before uploading to a webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896742/how-do-i-rotate-a-video-from-uiimagepickercontroller-before-uploading-to-a-webse)

I understand how to get the orientation of the video from the UIImagePickerController but How do I actually rotate the video url that the Image Picker returns so when I upload it its not rotated 90 degrees?

EDIT:

I'm using this method to get the orientation of the video. After I get the videos orientation how do I actually rotate it to that returned orientation?

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientationForTrack:(AVAsset *)asset
{
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[asset      tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
CGSize size = [videoTrack naturalSize];
CGAffineTransform txf = [videoTrack preferredTransform];

if (size.width == txf.tx && size.height == txf.ty)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
else if (txf.tx == 0 && txf.ty == 0)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
else if (txf.tx == 0 && txf.ty == size.width)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
else
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImageOrientation)getImageOrientationWithVideoOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)videoOrientation {
UIImageOrientation imageOrientation;
switch (videoOrientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationUp;
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationDown;
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight;
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        imageOrientation = UIImageOrientationLeft;
        break;
}
return imageOrientation;
}
```