# FFMPEG - Use Orientation metadata for mobile recordings

Tags: video, ffmpeg, orientation

When I convert a .mov file recorded on a iPhone 4S, the video is rotated 180 degrees.
If I playing the video on my computer, it looks correct.

I got the same issue with .3gp files from Android and .mov from iPhone 4 (They are rotated 90 degrees)

I have tried looking in the documentation for FFMPEG, but it seems that I will need to scan the metadata and then add it to my convertion script?

Command tried: ffmpeg -i VID_20120510_104204.mov -y -f flv -ar 44100 VID_20120510_104204.flv
Also looked on -vf %ROTATE%

Comment: This is a duplicate of your earlier question: [Orientation issue with mobile recordings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556063/orientation-issue-with-mobile-recordings).  See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions) for ideas about how to get attention for previously asked questions that you haven't gotten a satisfying answer to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a python script for detecting the rotation angle of a video from the metadata : https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtrotate/blob/master/qtrotate.py

You can use this with your conversion script.

Comment: Yeah you was right, needed to detect the rotation, and then rotate it myself.