# Displaying vertical videos with html5 on chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm building a simple [page](http://jsfiddle.net/JVZGZ/) to display videos uploaded from my iphone using the html5 video tag.

if you're watching it with chrome you probably see this video is presented horizontal, although it's not- try to download it or watching it from safari (haven't tried another browsers).

I havne't found anything on the net mention this problem, is it a known chrome bug? does this tag any attribute that I can change to display it properly?

Thanks.

**Edit:**
looks like this also happen in IE

Comment: Just for future folks.  IE11 looks to correctly orient the video of how it was recorded now, as well as Safari, but still looking for a better workaround for Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an encoding issue from iPhones.  I downloaded the video and it was still displayed horizontally using mplayer.  There is more information here:

http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/1508-video-orientation-for-iphone-wrong

and as suggested you'll need to re-encode the videos using a library that uses a more supported standard encoding.  (Or try to transform the video, on the page but that would be ugly)

Comment: Thx. I'm also the one that upload the video from iPhone, and I do know whether this video is horizontal or not, can I do something in the iPhone before I'm uploading it without re-encoding it?

Comment: Maybe.  Encoding would be something that is decently integrated into the software, so there's a chance you can't do anything but re-encode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208522/ffmpeg-on-iphone-modifying-video-orientation: though you could likely find an only service that you could use as filter before you upload.  There are several suggestions around (comments): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smVIRDfcEvU  but they are targeting Quicktime so that may be a "fix" within the problem rather than affecting the problem itself.

Answer (score 3):

you could use style="-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);" on the video tag along with a html5 compatible video player solution (otherwise you get rotated controls as well)

Comment: It's ok, I don't use the controls anyway. and I only need it for chrome for now, so that's mean that I don't need to be worry about  html5 compatible issues right?

Comment: This solution not good enough because it won't work on video that flipped in 180 (apparently there is a problem on those too), guess I have to re-encode the video.