# How can I determine video rotation/orientation in PHP/FFMPEG/PhoneGap?

Tags: php, cordova, ffmpeg

Once I upload videos to my server I'm creating a screencap using FFMPEG. Problem is, if the user takes a video in portrait mode the screencap is rotated 90º. The ridiculous things is that PhoneGap and FFMEG-php and FFMPEG don't seem to offer a mechanism for reading the video rotation/orientation value.

I found another library called [mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en/Download/CentOS) that will provide the info, but not in an easy to read/digest manner and I'm trying to avoid having to use another library.

Am I wrong about PhoneGap/FFMPEG? Is there a direct way to determine video orienation?

---

Here's my solution as a PHP function:

```
function get_video_orientation($video_path) {
    $cmd = FFMPEG_PATH . "ffprobe " . $video_path . " -show_streams 2>/dev/null";
    $result = shell_exec($cmd);

    $orientation = 0;
    if(strpos($result, 'TAG:rotate') !== FALSE) {
        $result = explode("\n", $result);
        foreach($result as $line) {
            if(strpos($line, 'TAG:rotate') !== FALSE) {
                $stream_info = explode("=", $line);
                $orientation = $stream_info[1];
            }
        }
    }

    return $orientation;
}
```

Comment: is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208522/ffmpeg-on-iphone-modifying-video-orientation

Comment: In a way, but I know that I can rotate the video using FFMPEG, but the problem is I don't know IF I need to rotate because I don't know what the orientation of the video is in the first place :s

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11236144/881551 and `ffmpeg -i video.mpg`

Comment: I looked at that one...ffprobe doesn't seem to give me the orientation/rotation value. I am using ffmpeg 0.6.5. Had trouble getting 1.0 installed on CentOS

Comment: See [Compile FFmpeg on CentOS](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide) for instructions.

Comment: Looks like everything compiled successfully; thanks for the CentOS instructions...now how do I run it/add it to my PATH variable. Where did everything get install to?

Comment: I took the build from source approach in order to use FFMPEG 0.9

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but sharing this because I spent all day trying to figure out how to get the orientation of a video with ffmpeg in php, so here it is (using laravelffmepg but works pretty much the same with native ffmpeg):

$video = LaravelFFMpeg::fromDisk('uploads')->open($media->filename);

```
        // Get video stream info
        $videoStreams = $video->getVideoStream();

        // Check if metadata exists
        if (!isset($videoStreams->all()['side_data_list'][1]['rotation'])) {
            // If rotation info is not available, use original width and height
            $media->width = $videoStreams->get('width');
            $media->height = $videoStreams->get('height');
        } else {
            // If rotation info is available, reverse width and height
            $media->width = $videoStreams->get('height');
            $media->height = $videoStreams->get('width');
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use MediaCodec to find the rotation value. Then rotate the video using FFMPEG.

Eg: ffmpeg -i in.avi -vf "transpose=1" out.avi

this will flips the video 90 degrees clockwise.